# Simplifying $(4m^3n)^\frac{1}{4} \times (8mn^3)^\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, exponentiation

The problem as given:
$$\left(4m^3n\right)^\frac{1}{4} \times \left(8mn^3\right)^\frac{1}{2}$$

distributed the exponent through.

$$\left(4^{1/4}m^{3/4}n^{1/4}\right)\left(8^{1/2}m^{1/2}n^{3/2}\right)$$

Then because $a^na^m = a^{n+m}$ and $a^{n}b^{n} = (ab)^n$

$$\left(2^2\right)^{1/4} \left(8^{1/2}\right)\left(m^{3/4 + 1/2}\right) \left(n^{1/4+6/4}\right) = 16^{1/2}m^{5/4}n^{7/4}$$

Am I correct?

Edited to fix mistake pointed out by "Old John"

Comment: Almost right - at one point you seem to have replaced $3/2$ with $3/4$ instead of $6/4$, but I think that is the only error.

Comment: you are right,also you can do $8=2^3$ so you take everything with base $2$

Comment: Very nearly there! in the line where you have $n^{1/4 + 3/4}$, should that not be $n^{1/4 + 6/4}$, giving $n^{7/4}$ in the final answer?

Comment: A possibly useful tip for these things: If you are unsure of an answer, try evaluating the original expression and your answer with some values for $m, n$ using a calculator. If they agree you *might be right*, but if they disagree, you *must* be wrong :)

Comment: "exponted threw"? Looks OK, but you can simplify $16^{1/2}$.

Comment: $16^{1/2} = \sqrt{16}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your answer looks good.  The one thing I would change is that I would replace $16^{1/2}$ with $\sqrt{16}=4$, giving you:
$$4m^{5/4}n^{7/4}$$

Comment: I tend to just keep the fractional exponent, just because it is easy for me.